# Change website directory safely to add a static page on startup

Tags: plugins, posts, pages, homepage

I have a blog http://aamirshahzad.net I want to have a static HTML page on start-up before user may see the blog. For that I am planing to move my whole site to http://aamirshahzad.net/web/ and want to upload the static html landing page on root.

Whats the easiest way to achieve that? any plugin etc to achieve this? I have searched but not found any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do, there is no need to move your site into a sub-folder.

The easiest way to do what you want is to simply create your static page in normal html just as you want it to appear. Then add the following code to the very top of your page...

```
<?php /* Template Name: Front Page */ ?>
```

Then save it as `front-page.php` and put it in your current theme directory.

Refresh WordPress and voila! you should see your static page.

Alternatively or if that does not work you can name it something else like my-static-front-page.php, then create a new page in WordPress, call it whatever you want, leave the content blank, and just choose the "Front Page" template you created, and publish that page.  Then in the dashboard go to `Settings > Reading` and choose `Front Page Displays... a static page.` From the front page dropdown choose the page you just created.

Comment: I knew that but this not what i need. That page will have a enter site button, by clicking that user will be redirected to homepage of the website.